# Unexpected Referring Domains in the marketing channel last touch report

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am analyzing the marketing channel last touch report for a customer.

I have two questions.

1. I have drilled down the report by Original Referring Domains. There are unexpected ‘Typed/Bookmarked’ domains related hits in the ‘Organic Search’ and ‘Affiliation’ channels, with non-trivial percentages. I have checked the marketing processing rules definitions:

   - A visit may be associated to the ‘Organic Search’ channel if it matches the natural search detection.
   - Analogously, the ‘Affialiation’ channel processing rule checks against the a certain value of the tracking code (tracking code = af).

So, why are there ‘Typed/Bookmarked’ attributions to the Organic and Affiliation channels?

2. How may I debug a marketing processing rule? Are there any tool?

See the following snapshot for details.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct data that you're seeing.

Because you are looking at the "Original Referring Domains" dimension, that visitor may have legitimately had an *original* referrer that was "Typed/Bookmarked".

For example (assuming cookies are never deleted). If I first visited your site on 1/1/2014 because someone told me about your site, and I just typed in www.yoursite.com into the address bar, I would have an original referring domain of "Typed/Bookmarked" because that is how I *first* encountered your site.

Let's say I make a second visit a year later on 1/1/2015 via Organic Search, and Omniture 'Natural Search Detection" assigns me as such.

Now, if you are looking at the Marketing Channels report for the year 2015, it will have this visitor as a visit under "Organic Search". If you then break it down by "Original Referring Domain" it will legitimately tell you that my *first ever* domain was "Typed/Bookmarked".